# swift protocol associatedtype

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a question about swift protocol associated type.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}

protocol TestAProtocol: SomeProtocol {}

protocol TestBProtocol: SomeProtocol {}

class TestA: TestAProtocol {}

class TestB: TestBProtocol {}

protocol Service {
    associatedtype S: SomeProtocol

    var service: S? { get }
}

class ServiceModule: Service {
    var service: TestAProtocol?
}
```

this code has an error because service's type in ServiceModule is a protocol(TestAProtocol)(not concrete type).

```
class ServiceModule: Service {
    var service: TestA?
}
```

or

```
class ServiceModule: Service {
    var service: TestB?
}
```

it's ok.

but I want to have a variable that conforms protocol(ex. TestAProtocol) that conforms specific protocol(ex. SomeProtocol).

like this:

```
class ServiceModule: Service {
        var service: TestAProtocol? // or var service: TestBProtocol?
    }
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work because you did no specified the associated type in your ServiceModule class and Swift compiler cannot infer the underlying type. You should use your protocol as a generic constraint instead:

```
class ServiceModule<P: TestAProtocol>: Service {
    var service: P?
}
```

Here `P` is a concrete type conforming to `TestAProtocol` which will be resolved at compile time. The caller (class init) will define the associated type. Here `P` will be of type `TestA`.

```
let instance = ServiceModule<TestA>()
```

The most important to understand is that you cannot use a protocol with an associated type as a concrete type. You can only:

- Use it a a generic constraint
- use the `some` keyword (only for functions and computed properties) to return an opaque type bidding the implementation.